# Rewrite url by htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Redirect every url parameter to index.php but I have some persian language parameter in url for url friendly but I have some issue with some words.

for example :

> NOT work : www.example.com/بیمه
>
> 100% work : www.example.com/تهران

It's not have any issue and it's work correcly and open index.php

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
```

This RewriteRule is work for english lang url parameter but I see error 404 in some persian language . maybe star (*) not meaning everything in this code .

> Page error is :
>
> Object not found!
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL
>   manually please check your spelling and try again.
>
> Error 404

Comment: Is that the only `RewriteRule` you have in your htaccess?

Comment: And the `.` means 'any character, except new line', and the `*` means 'match 0 or more times'

Comment: @Jakar no I  have few line more but these line is for url friendly . I try some pesian words and I see ( م ) char made this issue .

Comment: It's possible that the other rules are affecting this one. Are any of the others doing any URL rewriting? Do any of them have an `L` or `S` flag? Is there just 1 htaccess file or do you have some in subdirectories?

Comment: @Jakar I deleted other line but I see same result . How can i check which page apache wants load ? when I want load index.php